# low performance in binding function in view

Tags: html, angular, performance, ionic4

i have an ionic 4 with angular app, im also implemented websocket in my componentA.
componentA.html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of myList">
   <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
   <div>{{ calcPrice(item.price) }}</div>
   <div>{{ calcDistance(item.distance) }}</div>
   <div>{{ calcAge(item.age) }}</div>
   <div>{{ setColor(item.color,item.name) }}</div>
</div>
```

here a sample of myList:

```js
[
  {...},
  {...},
  {...},
  {...},
...
]
```

myList is an array and normaly contain 20 items, those items is updated with my websocket. I faceing a big performance issue when i enter the page, my app completely freeze when my list passes aproximately 8 items, so a started do to a big research and i discovery that using functions on view is a bad pratice

articles: [here](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496) and [here](https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16)

Every function that i uses have a return and I need those function do make calculations and etc, putting this inside html will make the code dirty and hard to maintein.

what i shoud do to make this work propertly? should i use pipes for each item?

Edit:

here is one of the functions that i used in my html

```js
  calcVolum(item) {
    if (
      TestClass.startsWithA(item.name) &&
      !this.needHelp(item.name)
    ) {
      return (
        Number(item.price.replace(this.regexPts, '')) *
        Number(item.currentQuantity) *
        item.age
      );
    } else if (this.needHelp(item.name)) {
      return (
        Number(item.price.replace(this.regexPts, '')) *
        Number(item.currentQuantity) *
        item.dolptax *
        item.age
      );
    }

    return (
      Number(item.price.replace(this.regexR$, '').replace(',', '.')) *
      item.currentQuantity
    );
  }
```

Comment: Shows more code to understand  what are you doing

Comment: the code i post is a sample, i will edit and post one of the real funcitons

Comment: every second my socket bring updates, so imagine myList updating values everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set up your component so that things are run when they need to be run.

write a function like:

```
calculateItemValues(items) {
  return items.map(i => {
    return Object.assign({}, i,
      {
        priceCalc: this.calcPrice(i.price);
        // however many else you need
      }
    );
  });
}
```

call that whenever you need to (when the items change), maybe like `this.calcItems = this.calculateItemValues(this.items)` or inside an rxjs `map` statement is usually a great place, and iterate the calculated:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of calcItems">
   <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
   <div>{{ item.priceCalc }}</div>
   <!-- whatever else you set -->
</div>
```

Comment: hmm i never thought of it, i will try here and see if it makes the performance better

Comment: if the socket emits every second, this means your calculations will be run once per second instead of ~500 times per second, so it's a gain, but once per second is still a lot of updates.. i'd wonder why this information isn't calculated server side if it needs to be to the second accurate, as the client isn't the best place for intense calculations... you also may benefit from adding a `trackBy` statement in your ngFor if the list is changing that often.

Comment: to be honest the performance now is alot better, about the trackby, I will implement soon, i already read about that,again ty :D

Comment: glad to hear it helped.  `trackBy` is useful, but will give the most gains with long lists or lists with complex sub components. a short / simple html element list won't do too much